# How to obtain Rinkeby DAI?

Tags: rinkeby, exchanges, faucets, dai

I need to obtain Rinkeby DAI token with this token address:

0x8f2e097e79b1c51be9cba42658862f0192c3e487

I tried a faucet and https://rinkeby.uniswap.exchange/swap - both give me a different token (however with the same token symbol "DAI").

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing where you got this address from. The contract is not verified on Etherscan: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x8f2e097e79b1c51be9cba42658862f0192c3e487#code. If you can find out the ABI of the contract, there is probably some kind of deposit function to mint you DAI.

Answer (score 4):

You can get DAI via compound!

This DAI has this address, not the one you have been looking for, but in 2020 it maybe different:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x5592ec0cfb4dbc12d3ab100b257153436a1f0fea

Just visit compound with metamask being on rinkeby:

https://app.compound.finance/asset/

1. go to "Supply" and click the desired token
2. in the modal go to "Withdraw"
3. click on "FAUCET", you will get 100 token

[image: Picture is for USDC, but same with DAI]

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no "DAI faucet", what you need to do is to get ether from a faucet and then you need to interact with DAI contract to send ETH into their contract, and then you'd receive DAI

Here's a guide that might help you: https://github.com/makerdao/developerguides/blob/master/dai/dai-in-smart-contracts/dai-in-smart-contracts.md

Comment: this link is dead

Comment: Not anymore - Even tho the correct answer is the one above :-)