# Good Ropsten USDC faucets?

Tags: ropsten, usdc

I'm trying to play around with the [DyDx Protocol on Ropsten](https://docs.dydx.exchange/?python#base-urls), but to get any further I need to have some USDC in my account. I've had no luck googling for this. There seems to be [this website](https://usdcfaucet.com/) for it, but it doesn't do anything, it just says ur USDC will arrive shortly but nothing happens after. The token contract is [this](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x8707A5bf4C2842d46B31A405Ba41b858C0F876c4), and I can see that there have been some transactions, but I don't know how I can exactly get some.

Comment: This is not going to answer your question but you could get ETH from a faucet and then change it on the Uniswap app. https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap. You can simply select your testnet account in Metamask.

Comment: Thank you @Peteris I was able to get some USDC through that.

Comment: However I'm still not able to make a deposit into my `dydx` account which is weird :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dYdX API endpoint can be used to request testnet tokens.

`POST v3/testnet/tokens`

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.dydx.exchange/#request-testnet-tokens) for more details.

Comment: oh nice! this must be new.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Compound Finance

https://app.compound.finance/asset/

2. Change the network to Ropsten in your Metamask

[image]

3. Click on the USDC market

[image]

4. Click on Withdraw and then Faucet

[image]

See similar answer for DAI: [How to obtain Rinkeby DAI?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82556/how-to-obtain-rinkeby-dai).

Comment: When I try this it just makes a zero transaction from my account to this address `0x9C3F0FC85EF9144412388e7E952eb505e2c4a10F` then nothing happens. I don't see the amount of USDC going up in my account.

Answer (score 2):

Try Uniswap protocol. Go to the https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap (you'll need metamask or similar tool).
The idea behind this is that you swap ETH for some other token. You can specify the contract address to define which token you need. I just did this for USDC in the Kovan testnet.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they have their own test USDC token they use for their testnet. I reached out in their discord and got some test USDC from one of their developers.

Comment: Could you add the discord link for future ref ? Thank you:)

Comment: https://discord.com/invite/dydx @DrGorilla.eth

Answer (score 0):

Now that Ropsten's deprecated (along with every other Ethereum testnet besides Goerli), make sure to get Goerli testETH from a reliable faucet (like https://goerlifaucet.com). Uniswap is a good option to switch between tokens.